# Electroweak phase transition and finite temperature field theory formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, phase-transition, higgs, thermal-field-theory

We do our calculations in standard quantum field theory at zero temperature where we can derive pole mass and renormalized mass and ...
Due to my understanding, pole mass is independent of any energy scale and is the same above and below the Higgs scale.

But when we try to work with finite temperature field theory formalism, we can calculate finite temperature propagator which has zero pole mass above electroweak scale(above critical temperature where phase transition have happened).

My question is that when we scatter particles at LHC(close to 7 TeV which is above 246 GeV), Do we use finite temperature results? Because when they scatter there is a local region in space-time with high temperature.

I think we compare our theoretical results at zero temperature with experimental results in LHC.

I am thankful to anyone who have useful comments for me